# emacs: copy without line number when using linum

Tags: emacs, copy-paste

In my work I do a lot of copying and pasting from the emacs and I'm looking for a way to copy chunks of code while using linum without copying the line numbers.

e.g.
1  bla
2  blabla
3  blablabla
4  end of stuff to copy

When marking lines 1-3 I'll get
1  bla
2  blabla
3  blablabla
Which is quite useless when trying to paste into shells or other places in the code.

Is there a way to copy without the line numbers and without enabling-disabling the linum every time?

Comment: The only way I can imagine that happening is if you're running Emacs in a terminal and using the mouse to copy the terminal contents. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: You'll probably find `M-x customize-group RET killing RET` and `C-h i g (emacs) Cut and Paste` useful (not for anything linum-specific, but for ways to make text which is copied/killed within Emacs available for pasting to other applications).

Comment: Yes @phils, that's the behavior I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a solid line separator

```
(setq linum-format "%4d \u2502 ")
```

Or a one space separator from line to buffer contents:

```
(setq linum-format "%d ")
```

Comment: nice, I think you just won your bounty. also see the same suggestion in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers , so I guess I need to learn how to search better :) .   an interesting thing I'd like to know though - the default value of linum-format is "%6d ", how come the default is copied and the modification isn't?

Comment: btw, the site will only allow me to grant you your bounty tomorrow

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to solve the problem. Is this question *not* about copying the contents of a terminal? Because that's the only way I could fathom that you might ever manage to copy linum numbers.